# Daily Word Count

Tags: wordcount

How do I keep a track of the Daily Word Count?
i.e. if I have a target of 500 Words/day for 5 days, how can I keep a Daily Word Count to ensure that I'm on par with my Daily Target?

Comment: Do a word count before you start. Write it down. Do a word count when you finish. Write it down. Subtract A from B. If it's less than your target, keep writing.

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing proper double spacing and margins, you get about 250 words to a page. So for 500 words a day, you need about 2 pages. Rather than words do a page, you will find it easier to keep track of.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like a graphic representation of your daily word count (though you need to input it yourself) I would recommend [Word Keeper Alpha](http://wordkeeperalpha.com/). You can track several projects and see your average word counts as well.

[image: Word Keeper Alpha word count tracking]

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Word has the ability to tell you the word count. All you do is highlight the text and enable the option (Review|Word Count). I imagine other word processors have a similar function.

Comment: Actually, Word constantly displays your current word count in the lower left corner, next to the page count.  It is a total count for the document.

Comment: @HenryTaylor - yes, but if you're only interested in the particular part of the document you've been working on that day, then you need to highlight the text and check the word count